# How can i split and get distinct words in a list?

Tags: c#, linq

My sample data coloumn, which come from an CSV file is

```
|----Category------------|

 SHOES
 SHOES~SHOCKS
 SHOES~SHOCKS~ULTRA SOCKS
```

I would love to split the specific column and get the distinct values in a list like

```
SHOES
SHOCKS
ULTRA SOCKS
```

I tried the following, but it does not work as expected.

```
var test = from c in products select c.Category.Split('~').Distinct().ToList();
```

It actually returns the following.

[image]

Any thoughts please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the collection:

```
products.SelectMany(p => p.Category.Split('~')).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `SelectMany` to "flatten" the list before removing duplicates:

```
products.SelectMany(c => c.Category.Split('~'))
        .Distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just needed to flatten out your collection to pull the individual items of each grouping via a [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) call :

```
// The SelectMany will map the results of each of your Split() calls
// into a single collection (instead of multiple)
var test = products.SelectMany(p => p.Category.Split('~'))
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

You can [see a complete working example demonstrated here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EDBOCO) and seen below :

```
// Example input
var input = new string[] { "SHOES","SHOES~SHOCKS","SHOES~SHOCKS~ULTRA SOCKS" };
// Get your results (yields ["SHOES","SHOCKS","ULTRA SOCKS"])
var output = input.SelectMany(p => p.Split('~'))
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Merge this list of `list of strings` into a single list by using `SelectMany()` and Just add another Distinct to your List..

`var test = from c in products select c.Category.Split('~').Distinct().ToList().SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it in query syntax.

```
var test = (from p in products 
            from item in p.Category.Split('~')
            select item).Distinct().ToList();
```